# Serverless Framework IAM allow RDS (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a table in my AWS RDS Postgres database. What would be the policy/action to allow this? When using dynamodb, the action is "-dynamodb:DescribeTable" what would be the equivalent for this for RDS (PostgresSQL)?

```
iam:
role:
  statements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        rds: * <- is this correct? 
      Resource:
        I DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE TO CALL RDS POSTGRES
```

Comment: may be ARN of the RDS_SERVER/DatabaseName

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the RDS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html) for policy examples. They clearly provide sample values for `Action` and `Resource`.